# Unable to mount network shares over VPN on Mac

Tags: vpn, macos, mac

I recently upgraded my server from OS X 10.7 to OS X 10.9. Since then I haven't been able to access network shares over VPN.

I am using iVPN to create the VPN server (I have tried with both PPTP and L2TP). I can connect just fine to the VPN and can ping the server and receive a reply. I can also access local volumes on this server via AFP/SMB.

However, most of my important files are on a Synology DiskStation and I am unable to access it. There are no issues when connected locally to the network, but I cannot connect via the DiskStation's IP address over VPN. I also cannot connect via name (e.g. afp://DiskStation.local) and it makes no difference using AFP or SMB. I get a message that the host is unreachable if I try to ping it.

The DiskStation has a separate IP address so I'm not sure if I'm supposed to do anything to accommodate for this, but I did not have to setup anything in advance to get it working on 10.7.

Also, I do not have a firewall running on either the server or DiskStation. The volumes on the DiskStation are mounted on the server but are not shown when I visit afp://10.0.1.100 (server IP). I am using an Apple Airport Extreme as a router and am connecting to the VPN on a Mac also.

Answer (score 0):

I figured it out. I guess newer versions of OS X disable port forwarding by default and unfortunately there's no UI for this so you need to use the following Terminal commands to enable it:

```
sudo sysctl -w net.inet.ip.fw.enable=1
sudo sysctl -w net.inet.ip.forwarding=1
sudo sysctl -w net.inet6.ip6.forwarding=1
```